# Auto Submit javascript

Tags: javascript

estou com um problema ao usar a função "submit();" em um input type="file" com um onchage passando uma id para a função, fiz um teste com um alert e está me retornando "[object HTMLFormElement]", não sei onde está o problema.

```js
function autoform(id) {
  alert(id);
  document.getElementById(id).submit();
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" onchange="autoform(form);" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

Comment: Está tudo certo.. a variável `id` passada é o form, e seu código está dando um `alert()` no objeto do form. O que você gostaria de fazer, de fato?

Comment: Eu consegui descobri onde estava o erro, no autoform(form) faltou o apóstrofo, ficaria assim para funcionar: autoform('form')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema na sua função é que o `id` não é uma `string`, e sim um objeto, que contém o form. Você poderia mudar sua função para:

```
function autoform(form) {
   alert(form.id);
   document.getElementById(form.id).submit();
}
```

```js
function autoform(form) {
   alert(form.id);
   document.getElementById(form.id).submit();
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" onchange="autoform(form);" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```